# How to replace values dynamically in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My URL structure:

```
/json/feed?car=${cars}&colour=${color}&model=VW
```

I want to replace what is in `${}` with JavaScript `var`'s I have available (`var cars`, `var colors`, etc.), however I am not sure how I can do this easily with Angular.

Would something like:

```
$scope.newString = oldString.replace("${cars}","cars");
```

Work ok, or is there a `%s` way of doing this with JavaScript ?
Which is a better way with Angular?

Comment: Instead of ${} use {{}} with your scope variables.

Comment: the URL actually comes back to me in a JS var that the server sends, hence why I'm trying to change the vars - those are placeholder tags sent

Comment: Okay. You'll have to do a replace like you did earlier except replace with your variable instead of a string. See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace with variable instead of string.

`$scope.newString = oldString.replace("${cars}",$scope.cars);`

Please take a look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NWdaatWSUBDZy4JYJvw1?p=preview) for reference.

You can simply chain `.replace`'s.

```
$scope.new = old.replace('${cars}', $scope.car).replace('${color}', $scope.color).replace('${model}', $scope.model);
```

Comment: How would I update the two values together, would: 

$scope.newString = oldString.replace("\${cars}","\${color}",$scope.cars,$scope.color);

work ok?

Comment: Work fine for my case.

Answer (score 2):

http://plnkr.co/edit/cFeD3tLOYWcPVwMAFQG3?p=preview

[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

You can use [interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) service of angularjs. Interpolate service works with angular js expressions,  which should consist {{ }}  instead of {} for replacement.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$interpolate) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
  function replaceAll(string, find, replace) {
    return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
  }

  $scope.interpolate = function ( ) {
    var context = { cars :"myCars", color:"red"};
    var url = "/json/feed?car=${cars}&colour=${color}&model=VW";
    var t1 = replaceAll(url,"{","{{");
    var url2 = replaceAll(t1,"}","}}");
    var exp = $interpolate(url2);
    console.log(exp(context)); 
  }

  $scope.interpolate();
});
```

> Output : /json/feed?car=$myCars&colour=$red&model=VW